# How to add `#[account(init)] or other constraints` to remaining_accounts?

Tags: anchor

When an instruction accepts fixed number of accounts, we can list all the accounts in a struct decorated with `#[Accounts]`, and add some constraints to each account.

However, if my instruction accepts variable number of accounts, how can I add constraints to them? My instructions accepts variable number of accounts that should be created and initialized. I'm wondering how to apply the `#[account(init)]` to each account? Or how to apply the exactly same initialization logic as `#[account(init)]` to these accounts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know this is not possible. You have two options to get around this:

1. Optional accounts will enforce account constraints if they are provided. This would allow you to add your accounts and only initialize them if provided. Here's the anchor PR that adds this feature for some more context: https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/pull/2101
2. You can manually implement the init behavior. Run `cargo expand > expanded.rs` on your program to see what logic Anchor is doing within the macros. Then you can manually iter over the remaining_accounts and run your constraints before mutating any accounts.

Comment: Thanks!! My instruction accepts an array of accounts of the same type, so I think your 1st approach can't apply. Regarding your 2nd approach, before I posted this question on stack exchange, I thought maybe there's a function that does all the initialization logic, and the `#[account(init)]` simply expands to code that calls this function. But it seems there's no such function lol, and I have to expand the attribute macro manually.